# jQuery Show Hide is not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below code is working fine in `Firefox` & `Chrome`, but it is not working in `IE`.

Can someone please let me know the alternate to hiding select `Dropdown` options?

I tried with `CSS` style `display: none` as well but not no luck.

```
$j("#id option[value='test']").hide();
```

Comment: try by adding the below cdn  sometimes it will be helpful                                <script src="http://yandex.st/json2/2011-10-19/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: whats `$j` ? jQuery ?

Comment: Please provide some more code (html+jQuery). it's really hard to understand and to check this one-line code.Every-one is guessing only. We don't know what is `#id` and from where it coming?

Comment: Can you create fiddle demo/example for this ?

Comment: You probably forgot to clear your cache in IE... Either that, or the cache was cleared, and your recent jQuery is problematic. jQuery should work on all Browsers. Not working? If you don't elaborate quickly, prepare for the question to be closed.

Comment: I cleared Cache still no luck

Comment: @iscmaro : $j = jQuery i my case

Comment: @magento12345 Please share your `HTML` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent lot of time to search on google related to same issue but changed my approach i tried the below scenario its worked like a charm for me

```
$j("#shipping_method optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").clone("optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").insertAfter("#shipping_method_form");
$j("#shipping_method optgroup[label='Free Shipping']").remove();
$j(".box-content .fedex").appendTo("#shipping_method"); 

#shipping_method_form   is my select box id
```

above is an example from my scenario please take a look 
hope this will be better solution for all browsers

Answer (score 1):

```
$j("#id option[value='test']").hide(); 
// use proper Id correct.
```

Replace #id with proper id of the element.

Comment: OP's code is working in `Firefox` & `Chrome`, it's not working in `IE`, if the ID is wrong then it will not work in any `browser`.

Comment: same thing i m using its working fine in firefox but not i IE

Comment: Ok, where have you placed the code in document.ready or clear the browser cache and try. if possible add jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option[value='test']").hide(); // here I assuming that you are not using ID

$("#idName option[value='test']").hide(); // here I assuming that you are using ID and replace `idName` with your IDs.
```

Comment: same thing i m using its working fine in firefox but not i IE

Comment: Yes agreed. Every browser have different rendering engine differently. 
By the way, instead of document.ready you can try direct `$(function(){ // add some code})`

Comment: can you please explain with any example so i will understand better

Comment: Before that line, I am sure you have `$(document).ready...` ?

Comment: Hmmm can you share the screenshot.

Comment: screen shot for what ?

Comment: initialize : function(orderForm, orderFormSubmit, shippingSelect, shippingSubmitForm, shippingResultId, shippingSubmit)
    {
        $j = jQuery;
        alert(22222);
        $j("#id option[value='test']").hide();

Comment: you need anything else

Comment: non-readable. Anyway, do let me know is that alert shows in IE ?

Comment: You need to add IE hacks.